# XSLT error when doing mathematical operations

Tags: xml, xslt

In a mule flow, I want to convert the time duration in format "hh:mm" in a xml file to seconds using XSLT.

For conversion I used the following,

```
<xsl:template match="EventDuration">
    <duration>
        <xsl:value-of select="60*substring-after(text(), ':') + 3600*substring-before(text(), ':')" />
    </duration>
</xsl:template>
```

But It gives the following error....

> XPTY0004: Arithmetic operator is not defined for arguments of types (xs:integer, xs:string)

What is the problem of this approach?

Comment: This error will be produced only in XSLT 2.0. Doesn't Mule use Xalan (an XSLT 1.0 processor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using XSLT 2.0, and in 2.0 you need to convert strings to numbers explicitly before doing arithmetic.

Your other option is to use date/time/duration arithmetic:

```
(xs:time(concat(text(), ":00") - xs:time("00:00:00")) div xs:dayTimeDuration("PT1S")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**number()**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-number) to convert the result of `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` from a string to a number.

Comment: This is because, as the error message indicates, `60` is an integer, but `substring-after(text(), ':')` yields a string. You can't multiply a string; you have to convert it to a number first.